# Alt keys in xdotool?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, xdotool

How to simulate left and right alt key presses with xdotool?
Have tried variations of the following in command line and scripts:
`xdotool keydown Alt_R key Alt_L ; sleep 1 ; xdotool keyup Alt_R`
`xdotool key Alt_R+Alt_L ; sleep 1 ; xdotool keyup Alt`
`xdotool keydown Alt_R+Alt_L ; xdtool keyup Alt_R+Alt_L`
`xdotool keydown Alt_R ; xdotool keydown Alt_L ; xdotool keyup Alt_R ; xdotool keyup Alt_l`
*etc*, *etc*, *ad nauseum*.
Phrasing doesn't seem to matter; unable to simulate both left and right alt keys together. Anybody know the "proper" way to construct this?

Comment: Without using xdotool, what do you want to achieve with both left and right alt down ?

Comment: @Philippe A keyboard shortcut and a custom panel button.